# Is there any option for setting a limit for password reset using custom policy in azure ad b2c?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom policy for authentication, in that custom policy i have a option for reset password, now i can reset the password for unlimited time in a day or so, i want to limit that reset password option to 5 times per day. Is there any option for that using custom policy.

I have tried some using custom policy but it throwing some error, I will add some portion of the custom policy here for reference.

Claims Schema

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_MaxPasswordResets">
  <DisplayName>Max Password Resets</DisplayName>
  <DataType>long</DataType>
  <AdminHelpText>Stores the number of password resets for the user.</AdminHelpText>
  <UserHelpText>Stores the number of password resets for the user.</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
<ClaimType Id="allowPasswordReset">
  <DisplayName>Allow Password Reset</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
  <UserHelpText>Indicates whether password reset is allowed.</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

ClaimsTransformations

```xml
<ClaimsTransformations>
  <!-- Other transformations -->
  <!-- Transformation to check if the password reset count is less than or equal to 5 -->
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertBooleanClaimIsLessOrEqualToValue" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_MaxPasswordResets" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="long" Value="5" />
      <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="lessOrEquals" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="allowPasswordReset" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
</ClaimsTransformations>
```

Here is the TechnicalProfile

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="CheckPasswordResetCount">
  <DisplayName>Check Password Reset Count</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <!-- Reference the claim that stores the password reset count -->
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_MaxPasswordResets" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="allowPasswordReset" DefaultValue="false" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <!-- Check if the password reset count exceeds 5 -->
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertBooleanClaimIsLessOrEqualToValue" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I have a sub journey for reset password in the User journey

```xml
<SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <!-- Step to check the password reset count before proceeding -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <!-- Check if the user is trying to reset the password -->
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>passwordreset</Value>
          <Value>true</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <!-- <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="CheckPasswordResetCount" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles> -->
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <!-- Perform a claims exchange with the custom validation technical profile -->
        <ClaimsExchange Id="MyCustomValidationExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CheckPasswordResetCount" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- Validate user's email address. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <!-- Check if the user is trying to reset the password -->
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>passwordreset</Value>
          <Value>true</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress-AcctExists" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- Collect and persist a new password. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <!-- Check if the user is trying to reset the password -->
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>passwordreset</Value>
          <Value>true</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</SubJourney>
```

I am not sure this is correct or not.

This is the error I'm getting:

> The InputClaims mismatched in ClaimsTransformation with id "AssertBooleanClaimIsLessOrEqualToValue" with TransformationMethod "AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue". The following InputClaims were declared in the Policy but were not expected by the TransformMethod: [Long]inputClaim. The following InputClaims were expected by the TransformMethod but were not declared in the Policy: [Boolean]inputClaim.`

I believe some can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You are asserting a boolean value, not a numeric one with transformation method `AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue`

You need to use `AssertNumber` transformation method instead.

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="isOverLimit" TransformationMethod="AssertNumber">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_MaxPasswordResets" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="Operator" DataType="string" Value="GreaterThan" />
    <InputParameter Id="CompareToValue" DataType="int" Value="5" />
    <InputParameter Id="throwError" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="attemptsCountExceeded" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

See: [Msft Docs - Claims Transformations: Assert Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integer-transformations#example-of-assertnumber)

But more importantly, I'd question why this is a requirement, it only hinders the user and their experience. What if their account is compromised and they can't change their password?
Are you going to stop them from going through the forgotten password journey, too?

How are you going to reset the counter after *n* hours?

Comment: Thats a good question. That i will check with my client. And i have no idea how to reset the counter after n hours. That also i need to analyse.

Comment: Short of having a timed function or logic app that updates every user and resets their counter, on the first change password you could save an extension attribute `extension_firstChangePasswordDateTime` and use [Date Time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/date-transformations#example-of-datetimecomparison) which would be more efficient _**if**_ they insist.